# Center the image and text below horizontally and vertically with background color of responsive height

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bg-color{
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #BA894D 0%, #FFBC6A 100%);
}
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.main-content div{
  max-width: 595px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 bg-color">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div>
                <img src="./download.jpeg" alt="LOGO" class="img-fluid">
                <h5>Brand Name</h5>
                <h3>Build your own shop</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore perferendis sit optio vero totam voluptatibus alias expedita, in neque natus, rerum officia nobis nihil, sapiente maxime beatae porro perspiciatis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is a contact form with 2 columns, One side is logo and text with the background of full height and one side is formed with inputs like name, email I want to center the logo and text below vertically and horizontally with a background color of 100% height.

Comment: Can you add some code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have added the Code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.contact{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.bg-color{
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #BA894D 0%, #FFBC6A 100%);
}
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.main-content div{
  max-width: 595px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row contact">
    <div class="col-lg-5 bg-color main-content">
        <div>
            <img src="./download.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            <h5>Brand Name</h5>
            <h3>Build your own shop</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore perferendis sit optio vero totam voluptatibus alias expedita, in neque natus, rerum officia nobis nihil, sapiente maxime beatae porro perspiciatis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you are expecting.